# Restrict object's creation

Tags: c#, .net, instantiation, encapsulation, access-modifiers

I have a very strange question here. I have Class A, Class B and Class C. I want to create object of Class B which can create the object of A. But how to restrict Class C from creating object of Class A.

One way is define Class A inside Class B, so that Only Class B can create the instance of Class A and Class C cannot access Class A.

But, I think nesting is a wrong way.

Do we have any way to restrict the object creation? Is it possible to use attribute and reflection to help to restrict? If possible is there a recommended way?

Please share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If by design **only** class B can access class A, nesting is a good solution. What you don't like about that?

Comment: in Real Word, purpose of Class A and Class B have two different purposes. When we define A inside B, then B's responsibility is not only to have Class A but also to have original purpose. Is it not violating SRP. Thank you.

Comment: Having class A doesn't mean *maintaining* it. Class A remains autosufficient like before. The *only* thing that changes is A class *accessibility*. That is *architecture* issue and not OOP, imo.

Comment: OK. But, just for accessibility, is it a good way to Defined A inside B. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can place class A and B in a single assembly and mark the constructor of class A as internal.

This way, only classes within that assembly can create instances of class A.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But All my classes are in the same Assembly.

Comment: There is no other solution possible. In C# there is not such a thing as a C++ 'friend' concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can make constructor private, and create fabric method that retuns instance of A, and parameter in this method will be instance of B.

```
public class A
{
  private A (){}

    public static Instance(B BInstance)
    {
       A result = null;
       if (BInstance != null)
       {
         result = new A(); 
         //create here 
       }

       return result;

    }


    }
```

Comment: This way a B is NOT creating an instance of A. You are only checking whether or not there is a B.

Comment: Thank you Aexandr and Erno. This is a good solution. But, there are few ways cheat the system. one way is:                                                       Class C
{

 pubic void SomeMethod()
 {
    B b = new B();
    A a=A.Instance(b)
 }
}                                                                                           what is your opinion about defining Class A inside Class B. is not violating Singe Responsibility Principle.