# Restrict class instantiation

Tags: c#, instantiation, encapsulation

In C#, is there a way to stop instantiating class, say after 'n' instantiations ? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061664/restrict-objects-creation) doesn't help much.

About trying out things, I was thinking of making the class static, but 
 'n' instantiations have to achieved before stopping the instantiations. Is it possible through Reflection ?

Comment: I think it would be of better help to you if you tell us what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Make a factory. Also, do you want to restrict it to 1? or N? If it's 1 then you want the "singleton pattern".

Comment: @John Restriction is to N. I am newbie in this; so please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a private static counter, increment it in the constructor and throw an Exception if your limit is reached. But notice, this is a very strange and most probably bad design.
A better way would be a factory pattern

```
class LimitedInstantiation
    {
        private static int instCounter = 0;
        public LimitedInstantiation()
        {
            instCounter++;
            // limit your number of instances 
            if (instCounter > 3)
            {
                throw new Exception("Limit of instances reached");
            }
        }

        ~LimitedInstantiation()
        {   
            // Reduce your number of instances in the destructor
            instCounter--;
        }
    }
```

You can test if like this:

```
try
{
    var instance1 = new LimitedInstantiation();
    var instance2 = new LimitedInstantiation();
    var instance3 = new LimitedInstantiation();
    // this should fail.
    var instance4 = new LimitedInstantiation();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pattern similar to the singleton pattern (except we allow multiple instances):

```
public sealed class LimitedInstantiationsClass
{
    private const int _maxInstantiations = 5;
    private static int _instantiations = 0;
    private static object _lockObject = new object();

    private LimitedInstantiationsClass()
    {
    }

    public static bool TryGetInstance(out LimitedInstantiationsClass instance)
    {
        instance = null;
        if (_instantiations >= _maxInstantiations)
        {
            return false;
        }
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            if (_instantiations >= _maxInstantiations)
            {
                return false;
            }
            ++_instantiations;
        }
        instance = new LimitedInstantiationsClass();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Essentially, only the `TryInstance` method can create an instance of the class* because the constructor is private. Within the class, we privately keep track of how many instances we've provided. The locking code is to ensure that this method is thread-safe, so that the most we will provide is _maxInstantiations (5).

The reason we check `_instantiations >= _maxInstantiations` twice is because this could change between the first check and acquiring the lock. We test outside to avoid the cost of acquiring the lock if no more instances can be created.

`TryInstance` will return false after the limit is reached.

** You can still create one elsewhere using Reflection, but that would be possible with almost any method.

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/UOTB78838)